# weird behavior of variables in anonymous functions?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function, variables, anonymous-function

Could anyone explain why the trace result of the code below are "5,5,5,5,5" rather than "1,2,3,4,5" and how do you make the anonymous function refer the collect element in the array?( in this example, "var item" should be referring list[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]).

```
var list:Array=[1,2,3,4,5];
var funcs:Array=[];

for each(var item:int in list){
    funcs.push( function(){
       trace(item);
    });
}

for each(var func:Function in funcs){
    func();
}

trace result: 5,5,5,5,5
```

Comment: closures the item for each func is shared and shows last item value

Comment: yours is the almost exactly BAD EXAMPLE from JavaScript: The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford:) try this to fix it:
`var helper:Function = function(i:int):Function
{
 return function():void
 {
  trace(i);
 }
}
` then change to `funcs.push( helper(item) );` what it does is pass current loop value of item tot he new closure created by helper

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela Still the most valuable information on this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the result of two things:

1. Function-level scope in AS3: the variable declaration inside `for each(var item:int in list)` is equivalent to declaring a `var item:int` at the beginning of your function (in your example, at the start of your code).
2. Anonymous functions are closures, which contain not only the code that you specify `trace(item)`, but also the environment for that code to run in. Specifically, each of the anonymous functions created by your code knows that it should use the `item` variable (declared at function scope) for printing (via `trace()`).

So, what happens is that `item` gets assigned all the elements of `list`, and then retains the last value (which is 5). It exists (does not go out of scope), and when those anonymous functions fire, each of them looks at the same `item` and prints the same value.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, this answer made me understand what was wrong with my code.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you create a closure which you access later.
For what you want to do you need to create multiple closures that can be later accessed.

```
var list:Array=[1,2,3,4,5];
var funcs:Array=[];

var closure_factory = function(index) {
    return function() { trace(index); };
};

for each(var item:int in list){
   funcs.push(closure_factory(item));
}

for each(var func:Function in funcs){
    func();
}
```